# Multiplicity issues in clinical trials for multiple groups

Tags: experiment-design, sample-size, multiple-comparisons, clinical-trials

Let's say we design a RCT for two different populations and want to test an intervention vs a control. It could be adults and children, male and female, etc.

We have one primary endpoint to be tested in both groups. But for each group we will have an intervention and a control, so two intervention arms and two control arms. E.g. intervention and control for adults and intervention and control for children. So the sample sizes are computed for each group.

We could have 60 adults in intervention arm and 60 in control arm. And 85 children in intervention and 85 in control. Because we assume different effects in each group.

If for the study to be considered a success, it is enough to observe a statistical significant difference in only ONE group, do we need to adjust for multiplicity, as if we had a co-primary endpoint? Is it considered a co-primary endpoint?

I am puzzled. As each group has its own control group. Or can these two analysis be considered as coming from two different studies? I would say we don't need to.

Any thoughts are welcome.

EDIT: Usually it more the other way around. We have one population where patients are randomized to one of the two arms and e.g. 2 endpoints. In this case, one method is to compute sample sizes for each endpoint using e.g. Bonferroni correction and then choose the largest sample size to make sure to preserve the type I error.
Here I am unsure, could we combine the two populations? And having a single intervention arm and a single control arm? Using some kind of stratified randomization? And then analyze the data using an interaction term between the intervention and the group?
Or is it a kind of subgroup analyses?

Comment: It's up to you to decide what it means for the study to be considered a success.  How you think about that would then dictate what / how multiple comparison corrections to use.

Comment: Do you want to *test* if the effects are different between the groups?  If you did, & you did not find a significant difference, what would you do?  Would you test the interventions in the groups together?  Alternatively, do you intend to simple *assume* they're different & proceed accordingly?

Comment: It might help to know what the intervention is (& more about the thinking behind the study generally).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To answer your questions: (1) to be considered a success it is enough to observe only one significant difference. (2) No, we assume a priori the effects are different in both groups

Comment: For (3), it is to test the effect of a post-operative procedure for two different kind of surgeries. Here we assume the effect will be different for each kind of surgery. This is why initially two sample sizes were computed. One for each kind of surgery.

Comment: If these are two unrelated surgeries on unrelated groups (eg, tooth extraction on kids, & knee replacements on the elderly), why would they belong in the same paper at all?

Comment: Good point! A procedure to prevent post-operative bleeding for knee replacement and hip replacement. In this case it is quite related... I think.

Comment: So the surgeries differ & the patient populations differ.  Is the procedure the same in both cases?

Comment: Yes, same procedure in both cases. You mean that surgeries and populations differ, because participants eligible for hip replacement are different from those eligible for knee replacement? So yes.

Comment: Based on what little I know here, & on common sense, it seems reasonable to imagine that the degree of bleeding prevention might differ.  But it doesn't seem reasonable to believe that in 1 case it reduces bleeding (however much) & in the other case it has no effect on bleeding whatsoever.  Does that sound right to you (&/or the PIs)?  If so, it seems like you want a single *test* of whether bleeding is reduced & two *estimates* of efficacy.

Comment: I agree with your thoughts and common sense. The effect should be beneficial for both groups but not equal although relatively close. As you say not no effect in one case. I think I see your point with one "overall" test for bleeding reduction and two estimates... But in terms of sample size, recruitment, etc. we would still need to stick to two sample sizes? One for the hip and one for the knee? Somehow combine both to get a single test, so no multiplicity issue?

Comment: If your question is how to get a sample size estimate, you would first decide on an analytical plan & determine the effect sizes you want to be able to detect.  Then I would simulate.  If you search the site, you'll find threads & examples for that.

Comment: No, it's not related to sample size determination. I assume they are known. So one sample size for each group. n for hip and m for knee. In this setting I would at first sight, make two "tests", one for each group. Because we might think it would make more sense to have a "single" test for bleeding reduction, I am wondering how to combine the two populations (n and m). Just pool both group, create an indicator for the group and then do some kind of analysis with interaction between intervention and group?

Comment: Also, I was thinking about your very first comment. This was +/- the whole point. Depending on the rule, how to address the multiplicity.  It's tricky only in case of a single hyptohesis is enough to declare success. Thinking again, it is not a matter that each group has its own control group, only what hypotheses need to be satisfied to get a success. Should be irrespective on the fact that testing is made on different populations or different datasets. This is/was my belief that the testing must be done on the same datasets. So if we stick to two "tests", I'd say we need to adjust... TBC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the conversation in the comments, I gather this is a study to examine if a new procedure will reduce bleeding following hip replacement and knee replacement surgeries.  The patients will differ, and it is believed that the efficacy of the procedure will differ between the two kinds of surgeries, but it isn't reasonable to imagine that the null is true for one surgery but not the other.  As a result, it is desired to allow the effect to differ between the surgeries, but to get a single test of whether the procedure helps.  At the same time, it is of secondary interest to estimate the two levels of efficacy.

I am thinking that I would fit a model with an interaction between surgery (population) and treatment (arm).  I would test the full model (controlling for whatever covariates you believe are appropriate a-priori) against a nested model that drops both the interaction and the treatment dummy.  That gives you a two degree of freedom test of whether the procedure helps.  This is a single test—no correction for multiplicity is needed.  Following that, the model will afford two estimates of efficacy for the two surgeries.  I would probably use 'least-squares means' to compute these estimates for a constant, idealized population, with special attention paid to confidence intervals for the estimates, not p-values.

Comment: Thanks, super smart! Give some food for thought on how to tackle a problem!

Comment: You're welcome, @user3631369.